# Symfony always saves checkboxes as zero

Tags: php, symfony1, checkbox, boolean

On Symfony 1.4.11 I have a boolean field that is set on a form by a HTML checkbox.  When the value is 0 (unchecked) then the HTML of the checkbox is

```
<input type="checkbox" value="" name="gift_type[valid]">
```

When I try and save the from it is always saved as zero, I assume because the input has no value.

The code I am using for the checkbox is generated by the symfony admin generator so I thought it would just work "out of the box".  If I uncheck a true value then that works as expected.

schema.yml

```
GiftType:
  columns:
    valid: { type: boolean, notnull: true, default: true }
```

BaseGiftTypeForm.class.php

```
$this->setWidgets(array(
    'valid' => new sfWidgetFormInputCheckbox()
));
$this->setValidators(array(
    'valid' => new sfValidatorBoolean(array('required' => false))
));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML checkbox looks funny,
are you sure it's been generated by symfony? (the id is missing i.e.)

```
<input type="checkbox" name="gift_type[valid]" checked="checked" id="gift_type_valid" />
```

Anyway all the code you show is OK, there is no need to change the schema type! (ping @richrosa). 
sfValidatorBoolean return a boolean value, then it's passed to the object, and then the object is saved. You have to debug your model. Out of the box, a boolean field in the Doctrine Admin Generator work perfectly fine.

You can add this code in your GiftTypeForm class to help debug:

```
  protected function doUpdateObject($values)
  {
    var_dump($values);die();
    $this->getObject()->fromArray($values);
  }
```

If you don't see the "valid" key boolean, there is a validation process error, if it's here, you have a model issue (have you overwrite the save method?).

Comment: It looks like sfWidgetFormInputCheckbox has been overridden by a file of the same name in /lib/vender/symfony/widget where its render methods outputs `$format = <<<FORMAT
<ul class="inputs-list">
    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="%name%" value="%value%"%attributes%/>
            <span>%label%</span>
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>
FORMAT;` I removed the offending code and it now outputs with an ID and works as expected.  Not sure where this code came from (I'm not the original dev) but I think this should solve my issues.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of how Symfony works. In plain PHP/HTML the value of the checkbox is independent of whether it is checked or unchecked. If a checkbox is checked it's value will be submitted in the form post; if it is unchecked it won't be submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your datatype to tinyint.

```
valid: { phpName: Valid, type: TINYINT, size: '4', required: false }
```

Here is a checkbox with a default value and a label.

```
$this->setWidgets(array(
'valid' => new sfWidgetFormInputCheckbox(array('label'=>'My Label') , array('value' => '1'));
```